# How to let Try Except output more details? To show where exactly did it happen? - Python

Tags: python

if we input

```
10/0
```

it will output: (Question here --- desired output while using Try Except)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python_Projects\00_Live\env\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3427, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-e574edb36883>", line 1, in <module>
    10/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

but if we use

```
try:
    10/0
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

it only output:

```
division by zero
```

How do we get python to output the whole errors like in the first case while using Try Except?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the basic `print()` function, the more flexible logging module can be used to log the exception. The logging module offers a lot extra functionality, e.g. logging messages into a given log file, logging messages with timestamps and additional information about where the logging happened.

try this :

```
import logging

try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
```

see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Comment: does my answer helped you

Comment: right, that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue raising the error (which will eventually result in exiting the program and printing a stack trace), you can put `raise` in the body of an `except`:

```
try:
    10/0
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise
```

If you want to print the stack trace but *not* raise the exception, see the `traceback` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Comment: How to get it in to a log? I am running the program in a cloud computer

Comment: One option is to have the caller of the program capture its stderr.  If you want the program itself to capture the stack trace, have a top-level exception handler that uses that `traceback` module to extract the stack info from uncaught exceptions and then print it to your log file.

Comment: oh you mean like 
try:
    10/0
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(e)

Comment: Yes, but rather than putting it around the `10/0`, you might consider putting it around your top-level `main` function -- that way you don't need to put it in every individual place that might raise an exception.  This is the huge power of exceptions -- because they keep on raising to the caller until caught, you can implement exception logging across your entire program with a single `try/except` statement!