# How to get full traceback in Python Notebook by using "%tb"?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, traceback

I ran some python code block on a Jupyter Notebook and got

> `An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.`

error/warning followed by a single line of traceback.

I want to see the full traceback as suggested. But I didn't understand what `%tb` is how and where I can use it. Is it an argument that I should've given to `jupyter` command or is it something I should've used in python code (sth like `printf("%tb", whatIsSupposedToBeHere)` )?

I have searched both this error message and ways to read tracebacks in python and j. notebook. I tried some answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-catch-and-print-the-full-exception-traceback-without-halting-exiting-the) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766048/how-to-let-try-except-output-more-details-to-show-where-exactly-did-it-happen?noredirect=1&lq=1) but couldn't get anything useful.

ps. This is not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
Yes I want to see full traceback (X) and I am asking a subproblem that encountered while trying a solution particularly `how to use %tb` (Y). However, i want to learn the solution of Y independent of its relation to solving X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `%tb` is a Jupyter notebook "magic" command

Just type it into an empty cell of the Jupyter notebook, and it will show the traceback of the last error you had on that kernel.

[image]

More info on Jupyter notebook "magics":
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html